# creating a new column in a pandas DataFrame - why is it taking so long

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I have a dataframe with one column - all the yahoo finance stock market codes for the ASX. (with the .AX exchange attached.

I am trying to create a new column in the DataFrame by applying a function to the yahoo finance stock codes which checks if the url is actually valid.

What I can't work out is why is it taking so long to create this new column?

My thoughts are it could be to do with 3 things:

1) I am using urllib2 and there is a faster library.

2) There is a much better way to apply a function than map to validate urls?

3) Because I am using a standard 2015 macbook air (though I didn't think 2000 records was very many regardless of the computer specs.

There are almost 1945 codes and it has taken well over half an hour.

```
def check_url(stock_name):
    url = str("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=") + str(stock_name)
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen(url)
        response = "valid"
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        response = "invalid"
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        response = "invalid"
    return response



yahoo["valid_url"] = yahoo["yahoo_code"].map(check_url)
```

In the end I just want to end up with a dataframe with two columns, the first which is the yahoo code, such as BHP.AX and the second column should have one word saying if the url is Valid or Invalid.

Comment: Creating a 1945 row column is fast, opening that many urls might not be. Have you tried timing a subset of the rows to see how long it takes?

Comment: @rurp on a subset of 10/1945 records it takes 5 seconds to create the dataframe.

total time = 5 * 200 / 60 = 16 ~ minutes. Is there some way I can write the above so that the urls are checked in parallel making it faster? It's taking much longer than the calculated 15 minutes. It's taken well over 40 minutes which is the time since I have written up this question.

Comment: Well, the URL request is probably the slow part here, there's probably no real way to speed that up, especially if there's some rate limiting being done on Yahoo's end. You could try doing the checks in parallel instead of one at a time, someone has written a library that does similar things [here](https://github.com/briwilcox/Concurrent-Pandas).

Comment: Hmm, your code runs fine for me on a small sample. As @Marius said it could be on Yahoo's end. I would try breaking up the urls and not opening them all at once.

Comment: Maybe rethink the problem.  Does yahoo allow you to query all valid stock tickers?  You could download that list, then this check would be done in memory on your side, not via URLs.